# Is there any method to convert string to map<int, dynamic>?

Tags: javascript, json, flutter

I make an API from Laravel and check the 'Get' request from Postman where it will return as follow:

```json
"answer_selected": "{1:\"True\",2:\"False\"}"
```

Then, the Flutter application will read the JSON and serialize it using the model class.

Are there any ways to convert the value of `"answer_selected"` to `map<int, dynamic>`? Or, my JSON API response format is incorrect?

Comment: `"answer_selected": "{1:"True",2:"False"}"` looks like a broken JSON in a broken JSON, and while it may be possible to hack through it, I would rather suggest fixing the generator code until it becomes `{"answer_selected": "{\"1\":\"True\",\"2\":\"False\"}"}` or perhaps `{"answer_selected": "{\"1\":true,\"2\":false}"}`. Then both the entire thing and the inner text could be parsed as JSON, like `console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.parse(thestring)["answer_selected"])["1"]);` would produce `"True"` or `true` (depending the variant picked)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not return a string that is not a complete JSON. Either return

- {"answer_selected": {1:"True",2:"False"}}

or

- {1:"True",2:"False"}

will be much better. `jsonDecode` in dart supports decode to `map<String, dynamic`, and the key in JSON must be string too. So the JSON should like

- {"1":"True","2":"False"}

If you want to transform it to `map<int, dynamic>`, just do

```dart
  void test() {
    String text = '{"1":"True","2":"False"}';
    Map<String, dynamic> map = jsonDecode(text);
    Map<int, dynamic> desiredMap =
        map.map((key, value) => MapEntry(int.parse(key), value));
    desiredMap.entries.forEach((element) {
      print('${element.key} ${element.value}');
    });
  }
```

Comment: Thanks Lebecca! I go through my JSON return query and yup, the format is wrong. I have made changes to JSON using jsonDecode